# Printing all errors in one go within twig

Tags: symfony, twig

I want to print all errors in one go for all the fields however `{{ form_errors(form) }}` doesn't print anything so because of that I have to use `if not form.vars.valid` statement to print errors however all the individual error messages are being wrapped within `<ul><li>Message</li></ul>` which is annoying. I know that `'error_bubbling' => true` solves the issue but creates another issue which is making field borders red.

How can I solve this issue? I simply want to print error without tags.

Note: I can use `{{ form_errors(form.name)|striptags }}` but it adds overheads cos my form is massive.

**FORM TYPE**

```
class BrandsType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->setAction($options['action'])
            ->setMethod('POST')
            ->add('name', 'text', array('label' => 'Name'))
            ->add('button', 'submit', array('label' => 'Submit'))
            ;
    }
}
```

**TWIG**

```
{% extends '::base.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}
    {{ form_start(form, {attr: {novalidate:'novalidate'}}) }}
        {% if not form.vars.valid %}
            <div class="global_form_errors">
                {{ form_errors(form.name) }}
                {{ form_errors(form.origin) }}
            </div><br />
        {% endif %}

        <div>
            {{ form_label(form.name) }}

            {% if form.name.vars.errors|length != '' %}
                {{ form_widget(form.name, { attr: {'class': 'field_red_border'} }) }}
            {% else %}
                {{ form_widget(form.name) }}
            {% endif %}
        </div>

        <div>
            {{ form_widget(form.button) }}
        </div>
    {{ form_end(form) }}
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Customize the field template

You can apply a form template to your form, check [this documentation at Form Theming chapter](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#form-theming).

If you prefer theming the field directly in your template, check the gray box in [this documentation at the Global Form Theming chapter](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#global-form-theming).

Check [this documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html) for more form customization.

## Pass the errors to the template

When you submit the form, your code will call this method `$form->handleRequest($request);` which will check if the user input properly the data.

Based on the [documentation of the Form class](http://api.symfony.com/2.4/Symfony/Component/Form/Form.html) you can get a list of errors by calling `$form->getErrors()`. The variable `$form` is an instance of the `Form` class and not the `FormView` class. You may want to enable error bubbling.

Now that you know how to get the errors you can pass them as a variable to your template.